# covariance of orthorgonal variables

Tags: statistics, covariance

For uncorrelated variables, the covariance should be zero. But for the two variables, x=0,1 and y=1,0. Clearly they are orthogonal and so they are uncorrelated. But the covariance is

(0-0.5)*(1-0.5)+(1-0.5)*(0-0.5)/2  = -0.25 not zero. What is wrong then? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, rather than programming.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Clearly they are orthogonal and so they are uncorrelated" - vectors can be orthogonal, this has nothing to do with random processes...
2. They are negatively correlated (one thing goes up when another goes down), everything is all right...

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance):

> covariance is a measure of how much two random variables change together.  If the greater values of one variable mainly correspond with the greater values of the other variable, and the same holds for the smaller values, i.e., the variables tend to show similar behavior, the covariance is positive.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) In the opposite case, when the greater values of one variable mainly correspond to the smaller values of the other, i.e., the variables tend to show opposite behavior, the covariance is negative.